# Why does JSF's ui:repeat add invalid tags to my HTML?

Tags: html, jsf

In my JSF app's page template, I use `ui:repeat` to iterate over some data to build an HTML table.  I want to use basic HTML tags for this rather than something like `h:dataTable`, because when I tried to apply some styles and JavaScript events to that, they didn't appear on the correct elements.  However, when using `ui:repeat` for this purpose, I find that it adds invalid `tr` and `td` opening an closing tags at inappropriate places.

The page template, has code similar to this:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <ui:repeat var="row" value="#{bean.testData}">
        <tr>
            <ui:repeat var="column" value="#{bean.testData}">
                <td>#{row}, #{column}</td>
            </ui:repeat>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

I actually want to do something more complex than this, but this is the simplest example of the problem.

The bean contains:

```
private final String[] testData = {"fu", "bar"};

public String[] getTestData() {
    return this.testData;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <tr>
        <td>fu, fu</td>
        <td>fu, bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar, fu</td>
        <td>bar, bar</td>
    </tr></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</table>
```

What I expected the output to be is:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>fu, fu</td>
        <td>fu, bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar, fu</td>
        <td>bar, bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can't figure out why JSF's adding this at the beginning and end of the `ui:repeat` loop's output:

```
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
```

In Google Chrome and Firefox, this causes an extra row containing a single, empty cell at the top and bottom of the table.

Any ideas of how to prevent this?

**Update**:  I didn't think to mention that this table I'm generating will appear inside a `h:panelGrid` element.  I don't know whether that will make a difference to this question or not.

Comment: Tested and working properly on my side (Mojarra 2.1.14).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the update, you need to encapsulate your code inside a JSF tag like this :

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <ui:fragment>
        <table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
            <ui:repeat var="row" value="#{bean.testData}">
                <tr>
                    <ui:repeat var="column" value="#{bean.testData}">
                        <td>#{row}, #{column}</td>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </tr>
            </ui:repeat>
        </table>
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Ortherwise the rendering of the `h:panelGrid` will not be able to split correctly in cell the nested content. `h:panelGrid` is designed to handle JSF components only.

More info :

- [JSF 2 h:panelGrid documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/panelGrid.html)
- [JSF 2 h:panelGrid example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-panelgrid-example/)

Comment: Thanks!  That makes a lot of sense now that I see it.  Would it make a difference if I use `h:panelGroup` instead of `ui:fragment`?

Comment: @LS, no it will work the same, only need to encapsulate since the `h:panelGrid` want JSF tags!

Comment: Got it.  I guess I might use `h:panelGroup` if I needed some of its attributes like `rendered`, etc.  Thanks again!